# Configuring Memoir page and font size for the Kindle3

Tags: pdf, memoir, fontsize

I'm trying to output a document sides for the Kindle3 and have a preamble that looks like so:

```
\documentclass[oneside,6pt,final]{memoir}                                      
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}                                                   

\pagestyle{empty}                                                              

\setstocksize{122mm}{91mm}                                                     
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}                                  
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}                                                            
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5cm}{0.5cm}{*}                                         
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5cm}{0.5cm}{*}                                         
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
```

I have two problems. The first:

```
! Class memoir Error: \headheight (12.0pt) and/or \headsep (18.06749pt) are  too large for \uppermargin (14.22636pt) by 15.84113pt.
```

Secondly, my font size directive is ignored: the default 10pt size is output. I do not rightly understand the first error and am rather surprised at the second. Would someone be so kind as to explain my mistakes?

Comment: As for the second problem, 6pt is not one of the supported font sizes in `memoir`, the smallest is 9pt. See section 1.2 "Type size options" in the `memoir` manual for a complete list.

Comment: True. Later in the document smaller font sizes are discussed, Computer Modern's 5pt. If possible I would prefer such a size as that, but I'm not clear on how to redefine the meaning of normal font size, or if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will help you on your way, I think:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[b5paper,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\pagestyle{empty}
\frenchspacing
\midsloppy
\setstocksize{4.5in}{3.25in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{5pt}{5pt}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{5bp}{5bp}{*}
\setlength{\headheight}{0bp}
\setlength{\headsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\footskip}{0bp}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{0bp}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0bp}
\checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\begin{document}
\tiny
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

That said, please note:

1. I'm using PdfLaTeX, mainly because I think `microtype` will help improve justification in such a confined space
2. I've set the other lengths to zero, assuming that you'll be using the `empty` pagestyle.
3. I haven't adjusted by dimensions to match yours exactly; I picked this out of an experiment I had lying around.
4. My approach to your font size problem is to use a 9pt normalfont, then reduce the text with \tiny. I fully accept that this is amateurish, but I'm afraid I don't have the necessary skills to copy and convert mem9.clo as mem5.clo, which is what I think would be necessary to do a "proper job"

I hope that helps.